# Invoke AppleScript from Outlook

Tags: applescript, ms-office

With the loss of the AppleScript menu in Outlook 15, what is the easiest way to launch AppleScripts from within Outlook?

In earlier versions, these scripts were located in `/Users/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/Outlook Script Menu Items/`.  Is this folder still relevant?

Comment: Located here now: /Users/[user]/Library/Scripts/Applications/Outlook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the AppleScript menu on the Menu bar. Script Editor > Preferences... > General

- Script Menu: [√] Show Script menu in menu bar

Place your *scripts* in: ~/Library/Scripts

[image]

Or create Automator Service workflows using a Run AppleScript *action*.

1. Automator > New > Service
2. Service receives selected *no input* in *any application*
3. Add a Run AppleScript *action*
4. Replace the default AppleScript *code* with you *code*.
5. Save the Service workflow. (They are automatically saved in: ~/Library/Services)

You can now access them from the Services menu in Outlook.

You can also assign a keyboard shortcut to any Service workflow that might be relevant to have one. This is done in: System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services

Or use a third-party utility like [FastScripts](https://red-sweater.com/fastscripts/).